# QuickSearch for files and directories

Tags: c#, performance, regex, file-system, search

I have a project where I need to search for directories and files. In fact I'm searching for paths in other projects. I don't want to just find files but I also want to exclude some directories or files from the results to avoid false positves.

In particular I'd like to exclude the following paths/patterns (not regex):

```
var directories = new[]
{
    @".git",
    @".idea",
    @".vs",
    @"_nuget",
    @"*.Tests",
    @"packages",
    @"TestResults",
    @"bin",
    @"obj",
};

var files = new[]
{
    @".xml",
    @".config",
    @".csproj",
};
```

There are not many wild cards in these patterns because files are matched at the end of the sting by default and directories are starting with a backslash ´\´. But it supports `*` and `?`.

---

The core type is the `QuickSearch`. It takes a path where it should start searching and optionally a `QuickSearchCriteria`. Internally it does not work recursively but with a stack. Based on the search criteria it is able to exclude/include both files and/or directories from/in the results.

```
public interface IQuickSearch
{
    IEnumerable<string> EnumeratePaths(string path, QuickSearchCriteria criteria = null);
}

public class QuickSearch : IQuickSearch
{
    public IEnumerable<string> EnumeratePaths(string path, QuickSearchCriteria criteria = null)
    {

        criteria = criteria ?? new QuickSearchCriteria();

        var directories = new Stack<IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
        };

        while (directories.Any())
        {
            foreach (var directory in directories.Pop().Where(DirectoryMatches))
            {
                yield return directory;

                if (criteria.Options.HasFlag(QuickSearchOptions.Recursive))
                {
                    directories.Push(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory));
                }

                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory).Where(FileMatches))
                {
                    yield return file;
                }
            }
        }

        bool DirectoryMatches(string directory)
        {
            return
                criteria.ExcludeDirectory.Matches(directory) == false &&
                criteria.Options.HasFlag(QuickSearchOptions.IncludeDirectories) &&
                criteria.IncludeDirectory.Matches(directory);
        }

        bool FileMatches(string file)
        {
            return
                criteria.ExcludeFile.Matches(file) == false &&
                criteria.Options.HasFlag(QuickSearchOptions.IncludeFiles) &&
                criteria.IncludeFile.Matches(file);
        }
    }
}

public static class StackExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this Stack<T> stack, T item)
    {
        stack.Push(item);
    }
}
```

---

The `QuickSearchCriteria` is just a simple class with several defaults:

```
public class QuickSearchCriteria
{
    public DirectoryFilter ExcludeDirectory { get; set; } = DirectoryFilter.None;

    public FileFilter ExcludeFile { get; set; } = FileFilter.None;

    public DirectoryFilter IncludeDirectory { get; set; } = DirectoryFilter.All;

    public FileFilter IncludeFile { get; set; } = FileFilter.All;

    public QuickSearchOptions Options { get; set; } = QuickSearchOptions.IncludeBoth | QuickSearchOptions.Recursive;
}

[Flags]
public enum QuickSearchOptions
{
    IncludeDirectories = 1,
    IncludeFiles = 2,
    Recursive = 4,
    IncludeBoth = IncludeDirectories | IncludeFiles
}
```

---

Filters are based on the `PathFilter` that provides some default implementations and stores patterns.

```
public abstract class PathFilter : IEnumerable<string>
{
    // Using just a few symbols Windows is showing when renaming files.
    public static readonly string InvalidFileNameChars = @"""<>|:*?\/";
    private readonly string[] _patterns;
    private readonly Lazy<Func<string, bool>> _matcher;

    protected PathFilter(params string[] patterns)
    {
        _patterns = patterns;
        _matcher = new Lazy<Func<string, bool>>(CreateMatcher);
    }

    protected PathFilter(Func<string, bool> matcher)
    {
        _patterns = new string[0];
        _matcher = new Lazy<Func<string, bool>>(() => matcher);
    }

    protected abstract Func<string, bool> CreateMatcher();

    public bool Matches(string path)
    {
        return path == null ? false : _matcher.Value(path);
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<string>)_patterns).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

Filters I currently use are regex-based so the use another base class the `RegexPathFilter`. This class encapsulates common conversion of patterns to regex. Patterns that start and and with a slash `/` are considered as regex.

```
public abstract class RegexPathFilter : PathFilter
{
    protected RegexPathFilter(params string[] patterns) : base(patterns) { }

    protected RegexPathFilter(Func<string, bool> matcher) : base(matcher) { }

    protected override Func<string, bool> CreateMatcher()
    {
        var regexPatterns = this.ToLookup(IsRegex);
        var expressions = regexPatterns[true].Select(p => p.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/')).Concat(CreateRegularExpressions(regexPatterns[false]));
        var regex = new Regex($"({string.Join("|", expressions)})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return regex.IsMatch;

        bool IsRegex(string value) => value.StartsWith("/") && value.EndsWith("/");
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<string> CreateRegularExpressions(IEnumerable<string> patterns)
    {
        return 
            from pattern in patterns 
            select Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\.", @"\.") into pattern 
            select Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\?", @".") into pattern 
            // Hard to decide which one to use.
            //select Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\*", $@"[^{Regex.Escape(InvalidFileNameChars)}]*?") into pattern
            select Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\*", $@".*?");
    }
}
```

---

The two main filters are the `DirectoryFilter` and the `FileFilter`. Each of them customizes the patters further to create the final version that either must start with a `\` or be at the end of the string so that I don't have to use `.*?` for common exclusions like `*.cs`.

```
public class DirectoryFilter : RegexPathFilter
{
    public DirectoryFilter(params string[] patterns) : base(patterns) { }

    private DirectoryFilter(Func<string, bool> matcher) : base(matcher) { }

    public static DirectoryFilter None => new DirectoryFilter(_ => false);

    public static DirectoryFilter All => new DirectoryFilter(_ => true);

    public static DirectoryFilter Create(params string[] patterns)
    {
        return new DirectoryFilter(patterns);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<string> CreateRegularExpressions(IEnumerable<string> patterns)
    {
        // Directories are matched at the \
        return base.CreateRegularExpressions(patterns).Select(p => @"\\" + p);
    }
}

public class FileFilter : RegexPathFilter
{
    public FileFilter(params string[] patterns) : base(patterns) { }

    private FileFilter(Func<string, bool> matcher) : base(matcher) { }

    public static FileFilter None => new FileFilter(_ => false);

    public static FileFilter All => new FileFilter(_ => true);

    public static FileFilter Create(params string[] patterns)
    {
        return new FileFilter(patterns);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<string> CreateRegularExpressions(IEnumerable<string> patterns)
    {
        // Files are matched at the end of the string.
        return base.CreateRegularExpressions(patterns).Select(p => p + "$");
    }
}
```

---

**Example** To use it I just need to instantiate the `QuickSearch` and give it some search criteria:

```
var ignore = (DirectoryFilter.Create(directories), FileFilter.Create(files));

var pathEnumerator = new QuickSearch();

pathEnumerator
    .EnumeratePaths(@"c:\temp\projects\testproject", new QuickSearchCriteria
    {
        ExcludeDirectory = ignore.Item1,
        ExcludeFile = ignore.Item2
    })
    .Count()
    .Dump();
```

---

It takes 0.040sec to enumerate a directory with 10.600 files and 1.400 folders yealding 417 results with the above ignore list on my notebook's SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...many refactorings later.

I came to the conclustion that this soltion was totaly overengineered. I simplified it and made more LINQ-friendly by using `Func` instead of the custom type `PathFilter` and the `QuickSearchCriteria`.

The core type is now the `IFileSytem` that is easier to use with DI and easier to mock. `EnumerateDirectories` just needs one parameter to make it faster, this is exclude directories, everything else I can filter outside later.

```
public interface IFileSystem
{
    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string path, Func<string, bool> exclude, bool deep = true);

    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path);
}
```

Its implementation has also become simpler because the big `EnumeratePaths` method is now two methods.

```
public class FileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string path, Func<string, bool> exclude, bool deep = true)
    {
        if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

        var directories = new Stack<string>
        {
            path,
        };

        while (directories.Any())
        {
            foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directories.Pop()).Skip(exclude))
            {
                yield return directory;

                if (deep)
                {
                    directories.Push(directory);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path)
    {
        if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

        return
            from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
            select file;
    }
}
```

To get files I can just use `SelectMany`:

> ```
> var nuspecFilter = FileFilterFactory.Default.Create(".nuspec");
>
> fileSystem
>   .EnumerateDirectories(
>         @"c:\temp\projects\testproject",
>         directoryExclusions
>             .Select(DirectoryFilterFactory.Default.Create)
>             .ToList()
>             .ToAny(),
>      deep: true)
>   .SelectMany(pathEnumerator.EnumerateFiles)
>   .Where(nuspecFilter)
>   .Dump();
> ```

where `ToAny` is implemented as

```
public static Func<TElement, bool> ToAny<TElement>(this IEnumerable<Func<TElement, bool>> filters)
{
    return x => filters.Any(f => f(x));
}
```

---

The rest of the code now implements the `IFilterFactory` interface.

```
public interface IFilterFactory<TElement, TCondition>
{
    Func<TElement, bool> Create(TCondition condition);
}
```

Currently there is only one such filter, the `PathFilterFactory`. This can create filters from three kinds of patterns:

- `/regex/` - matches with user regex
- `*.wildcardex` - matches with regex compiled from wildcards
- `stringex` - matches files by `EndsWith(stringex)` and directories by `IndexOf("\" + stringex)`

(for the sake of consistency I add the *ex* at the end).

```
public abstract class PathFilterFactory : IFilterFactory<string, string>
{
    // Using just a few symbols Windows is showing when renaming files.
    public static readonly string InvalidFileNameChars = @"""<>|:*?\/"; 

    public static Func<string, bool> None => _ => false;

    public static Func<string, bool> All => _ => true;

    private IEnumerable<(Func<string, bool> Condition, Func<string, Func<string, bool>> Factory)> _factories;

    protected PathFilterFactory()
    {
        _factories = new(Func<string, bool> Condition, System.Func<string, Func<string, bool>>)[]
        {
            (IsRegex, FromRegex),
            (IsWildcardex, FromWildcardex),
            (_ => true, FromStringex),
        };
    }

    public Func<string, bool> Create(string pattern)
    {
        return 
            _factories
                .First(t => t.Condition(pattern))
                .Factory(pattern);
    }

    protected virtual Func<string, bool> FromRegex(string pattern)
    {
        return new Regex(pattern.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch;
    }

    protected abstract Func<string, bool> FromWildcardex(string pattern);   

    protected abstract Func<string, bool> FromStringex(string pattern);

    private static bool IsRegex(string value)
    {
        return
            value.StartsWith("/") &&
            value.EndsWith("/");
    }

    private static bool IsWildcardex(string value)
    {
        return
            value.Contains('*') ||
            value.Contains('?');
    }
}

public class DirectoryFilterFactory : PathFilterFactory
{
    public static readonly IFilterFactory<string, string> Default = new DirectoryFilterFactory();

    protected override Func<string, bool> FromWildcardex(string pattern)
    {
        pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\.", @"\.");
        pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\?", @".");
        // Hard to decide which one to use.
        //result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\*", $@"[^{Regex.Escape(InvalidFileNameChars)}]*?");
        pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\*", $@".*?");

        // Directories are matched at the '\'
        pattern = @"\\" + pattern;

        return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch;
    }

    protected override Func<string, bool> FromStringex(string pattern)
    {
        pattern = @"\" + pattern;
        return path => path.IndexOf(pattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}

public class FileFilterFactory : PathFilterFactory
{
    public static readonly IFilterFactory<string, string> Default = new FileFilterFactory();

    protected override Func<string, bool> FromWildcardex(string pattern)
    {
        pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\.", @"\.");
        pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\?", @".");
        // Hard to decide which one to use.
        //result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\*", $@"[^{Regex.Escape(InvalidFileNameChars)}]*?");
        pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\*", $@".*?");

        // Files are matched at the end of the string.
        pattern = pattern + "$";

        return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch;
    }

    protected override Func<string, bool> FromStringex(string pattern)
    {
        return path => path.EndsWith(pattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```